# How to send large file using UDPClient? C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udpclient

I am trying to send images from one pc to another and I need it to be fast (streaming), that is why I cannot use TCP, TCP is too slow, how can I send large files without using TCP?

this is what I've tried with TCP:

ServerClass

```
 //This is running by a thread
private void SendImage()
    {
        while (Status == ServerStatus.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = Desktop.TakeScreenShoot();
                Desktop.SerializeScreen(_NetStream,bitmap);
            }
            catch
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

DesktopClass

```
public static void SerializeScreen(Stream stream, Bitmap Image)
    {
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        Image.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        int numBytes = (int)memory.Length;
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        binaryWriter.Write(numBytes);
        binaryWriter.Write(memory.GetBuffer(), 0, numBytes);
    }

    public static Image DeserializeScreen(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        int numBytes = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        byte[] buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(numBytes);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        return Image.FromStream(memory);
    }
```

ClientClass

```
private void ReciveMessageAsync()
    {
        while (Status == ServerStatus.Connected)
        {
            ReciveMessage();
            
        }
    }
 protected override void ReciveMessage()
    {
        try
        {
        //this is an event that recive the Image to show on the picturebox               
        
        ImageRecibed?.Invoke(Desktop.DeserializeScreen(_NetStream));
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            _NetStream.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Here is a demo [video demo](https://youtu.be/QwC-IUb7t30)

Comment: "TCP is too slow" - what have you tried, what speed did you get, and what speed do you need? While there *are* reasons to use UDP instead of TCP, it's also significantly more complex... and if the PCs are on the same LAN I'd expect the transfer speed to be pretty good.

Comment: RTSP, they protocol almost every streaming platform uses, runs on TCP and does just fine. It sounds like a "your code" problem.

Comment: You can try to make something by yourself based on UDP. UDP doesn't do all the nice things TCP does - that's why it's "faster". Good luck!

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: don't blindly swallow exceptions

Comment: If it goes faster than 10 milliseconds then the receiver deliberately lags behind. Is that really what you want it to do?

Comment: I just deleted the thread.sleep(10) and it is still slow, here is a video of my project, the mouse on my host moves fast but the image received by the client is too slow https://youtu.be/QwC-IUb7t30

Comment: "TCP is too slow". How do you know? And even if it is, do you care about reliability? What if some packets get lost while using UDP and you only get a partial image? Do you care about that? Because if you do, then it is irrelevant how performant TCP is. You have to use it (even though technically you could reimplement TCP over UDP, like QUIC does, you won't see relevant performance improvement - QUIC is better because of other reasons).

Comment: @Blindy "*RTSP, they protocol almost every streaming platform uses, runs on TCP*" - RTSP itself, which handles commands to control media operations, runs on TCP. But the actual media streams themselves run on UDP using RTP/RTCP instead.

Comment: @LuisGarcia "*how can I send large files without using TCP?*" - you could use a UDP-based transfer protocol, such as TFTP or UDT.

Comment: Looking at the code, it's of extremely poor quality. You should be parallelizing the desktop capture and image encoding. Also both encoding and decoding use this needless second memory stream for no reason other than to copy bytes around for fun. Decoding is actually twice as bad, because you're also allocating a byte array and copying that.

Comment: @Blindy so, How can I improve it?, I'm new in Sockets and sharing data, can u give me an example?

Comment: In the serializer, simply save your image directly to your output stream. In the deserializer, simply read your image from the input stream. And every time you reach for a `MemoryStream`, simply slap yourself. Problem solved!

Comment: @Blindy I tried, I used the client's Image.save() method, but the Image.FromStream() method doesn't read the image and keeps waiting for the message from the client

Comment: You need to be posting a lot more code and drawing a lot less conclusions from problems. If the mess you did write works, then you can write it correctly as well, without the additional streams and buffers and whatnot.